# Recursive IDs and duplicating form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/XpAk5/63/

The IDs increment appropriately.  For the first instance.  The issue is when I try to add a sport, while it duplicates, it doesn't duplicate correctly.  The buttons to add are not creating themselves correctly.  For instance, if I choose a sport, then fill in a position, and add another position, that's all fine (for the first instance).  But when I click to add another sport, it shows 2 positions right away, and the buttons aren't duplicating correctly.  I think the error is in my HTML, but not sure.  Here is the JS I am using to duplicate the sport:

```
$('#addSport').click(function(){
    //increment the value of our counter
    $('#kpSport').val(Number($('#kpSport').val()) + 1);
    //clone the first .item element
    var newItem = $('div.kpSports').first().clone();
    //recursively set our id, name, and for attributes properly
    childRecursive(newItem, 
        // Remember, the recursive function expects to be able to pass in
        // one parameter, the element.
        function(e){
            setCloneAttr(e, $('#kpSport').val());
    });
    // Clear the values recursively
    childRecursive(newItem, 
        function(e){
            clearCloneValues(e);
    });
```

Hoping someone has an idea, perhaps I've just got my HTML elements in the wrong order?  Thank you for your help!  I'm hoping the fiddle is more helpful than just pasting a bunch of code here in the message.

Comment: why not use a template instead of cloning elements? If the user can make changes to the elements you want to clone, and you have to try to reset all those elements to their default state, why not just make a function return the html elements from a template?

Comment: That's not your only problem. You are cloning the inputs as well, when a Position is added.

Comment: It appears that I have something new to learn.  Do you know where I could find something on how to do these templates?  I try to search and I'm not searching the right terms it seems, because I'm getting more website templates.   Thank you for your help/suggestion!

Comment: google "underscore templates"

Comment: For a broader result search try: [javascript client side templates](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww#hl=en&q=javascript+client+side+templates).  Depending the library, the learning curve can be a bit steep.  If your immediate needs are met, it may make more sense to start with a home built approach as in my answer below.  Then, as you get a better feel for your application's requirements, you can choose a solution that best solves those specific problems.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your `clearCloneValues` function.  It doesn't differentiate between buttons and other for elements that you do want to clear.

Change it to:

```
// Sets an element's value to ''
function clearCloneValues(element){
    if (element.attr('value') !== undefined && element.attr('type') !== 'button'){
        element.val('');
    }
}
```

As @PHPglue pointed out in the comments above, when new positions are added, they are incorrectly replicated (I'm assuming here) to the newly cloned for

There is a similar problem with the add years functionality.

A quick fix would be to initialize a variable with a clone of the original form fields:

```
var $template = $('div.kpSports').first().clone();
```

Then change your `addSport` handler to:

```
$('#addSport').click(function () {
    //increment the value of our counter
    $('#kpSport').val(Number($('#kpSport').val()) + 1);
    //clone the first .item element
    var newItem = $template.clone();
    …
});
```

However, there are no event bindings for the new buttons, so that functionality is still missing for any new set of form elements.

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/XpAk5/65/)

---

Using even a simple, naive string based templates the code can be simplified greatly.  Linked is an **untested** fiddle that shows how it might be done using this approach.

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/XpAk5/68/)

The code was simplified to the following:

```
function getClone(idx) {
    var $retVal = $(templates.sport.replace(/\{\{1\}\}/g, idx));

    $retVal.find('.jsPositions').append(getItemClone(idx, 0));
    $retVal.find('.advtrain').append(getTrainingClone(idx, 0));
    return $retVal;
}

function getItemClone(setIdx, itemIdx) {
    var retVal = itemTemplate.replace(/\{\{1\}\}/g, setIdx).replace(/\{\{2\}\}/g, itemIdx);
    return $(retVal);
}

function getTrainingClone(setIdx, trainingIdx) {
    var retVal = trainingTemplate.replace(/\{\{1\}\}/g, setIdx).replace(/\{\{2\}\}/g, trainingIdx);
    return $(retVal);
}

$('#kpSportPlayed').on('click', '.jsAddPosition', function() {
    var $container = $(this).closest('.kpSports');
    var containerIdx = $container.attr('data_idx');
    var itemIdx      = $container.find('.item').length;

    $container.find('.jsPositions').append(getItemClone(containerIdx, itemIdx));
});

$('#kpSportPlayed').on('click', '.jsAddTraining', function() {
    var $container = $(this).closest('.kpSports');
    var containerIdx = $container.attr('data_idx');
    var trainIdx = $container.find('.advtrain > div').length;

    $container.find('.advtrain').append(getTrainingClone(containerIdx, trainIdx));
});

$('#addSport').click(function () {
    var idx = $('.kpSports').length;
    var newItem = getClone(idx);

    newItem.appendTo($('#kpSportPlayed'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you!  It seems perhaps I'm doing this in a more difficult way than I need?  Would cloning a template be the better/easier/futureproof route?

Comment: Yes - there are many ways to create a template, but one would be to use a string based approach, then pass in the numeric offset for the id to a function that returns the realized clone.  Another would be to use jQuery to build the resulting form (.append/.appendTo, etc) again passing in the numeric offset.  There are also many templating libraries you could use for this as well.

Comment: BTW: there is another bug with ID's of dynamic child elements - ID's are being duplicated (check your position input ID's as an example)

Comment: @lobstahcrushah I've added a simple template based sample - I think I caught most of the issues mentioned previously with it.  YMMV :)

Comment: Can't thank you enough dc5!  Do you have a website or contact info?  Have a question for you.  Thank you again!